# Error while accessing DXA 1.4 website

Tags: dxa, web8, dxa-1.4

I have installed DXA 1.4 (with Web 8) as per the documentation. Now I am getting the below error when trying to access the Example website  -

> No matching Localization found for URL 'http://localhost:90/'

Here is my Mapping -

```
{  
   "@odata.context":"http://localhost:82/ttm201501/$metadata#Mappings",
   "value":[  
      {  
         "Id":"Mapping1",
         "ExtensionProperties":[  

         ],
         "CmEnvironmentId":"Tridioncm_TRID01",
         "PublicationId":"tcm:0-15-1",
         "EnvironmentPurpose":"Staging",
         "WebApplicationId":"Website1_RootWebApp",
         "RelativeUrl":"/",
         "PrimaryMappedUrl":"http://localhost:90/",
         "IsOffline":false
      }
   ]
}
```

Please suggest if I have missed an step -

Log Details -

> 2016-06-29 11:15:38,399 [1] DEBUG -
>   BaseAreaRegistration.RegisterArea() exit. Duration: 22 ms.
>
> 2016-06-29 11:15:38,423 [8] DEBUG -
>   StaticContentModule.BeginRequest(ASP.global_asax, System.EventArgs) :
>   "/" entry.
>
> 2016-06-29 11:15:38,425 [8] DEBUG -
>   CdApiLocalizationResolver.ResolveLocalization(http://localhost:90/)
>   entry.
>
> 2016-06-29 11:15:38,633 [8] DEBUG -
>   CdApiLocalizationResolver.ResolveLocalization() exit. Duration: 207
>   ms.
>
> 2016-06-29 11:15:38,634 [8] WARN  - No matching Localization found for
>   URL 'http://localhost:90/'. Sending HTTP 404 (Not Found) response.
>
> 2016-06-29 11:15:38,634 [8] DEBUG - StaticContentModule.BeginRequest()
>   exit. Duration: 211 ms.

Comment: Did you publish the Settings folder ?

Comment: Anything useful in your Content Service log file(s)?  Try using the `Sync-TtmCdEnvironment` cmdlet to ensure your CD Discovery Service is in sync with your Topology Manager.