# Error while accessing DXA 1.6 website

Tags: web8, dxa

The publish of 400 Example Site succeeded.
But when I tried to access the site, following message was shown on the window.

```
No matching Localization found for URL 'http://MyServer:90/'
```

Then I checked the log file. Below is the detail.

```
2016-12-02 15:48:41,717 [1] INFO  - -------- Initializing DXA Framework v1.6.0.223 --------
2016-12-02 15:48:41,858 [1] INFO  - Using implementation type 'Sdl.Web.Tridion.DefaultCacheProvider' for interface ICacheProvider.
2016-12-02 15:48:41,874 [1] INFO  - Using implementation type 'Sdl.Web.Tridion.Mapping.DefaultContentProvider' for interface IContentProvider.
2016-12-02 15:48:41,874 [1] INFO  - Using implementation type 'Sdl.Web.Tridion.Navigation.StaticNavigationProvider' for interface INavigationProvider.
2016-12-02 15:48:44,842 [1] INFO  - Using implementation type 'Sdl.Web.Tridion.Context.ContextServiceClaimsProvider' for interface IContextClaimsProvider.
2016-12-02 15:48:44,842 [1] INFO  - Using implementation type 'Sdl.Web.Tridion.Linking.DefaultLinkResolver' for interface ILinkResolver.
2016-12-02 15:48:44,842 [1] INFO  - Using implementation type 'Sdl.Web.Tridion.Mapping.DefaultRichTextProcessor' for interface IRichTextProcessor.
2016-12-02 15:48:44,842 [1] INFO  - No implementation type configured for optional interface IConditionalEntityEvaluator.
2016-12-02 15:48:44,842 [1] INFO  - Using implementation type 'Sdl.Web.Mvc.Html.BaseMediaHelper' for interface IMediaHelper.
2016-12-02 15:48:44,842 [1] INFO  - Using implementation type 'Sdl.Web.Tridion.CdApiLocalizationResolver' for interface ILocalizationResolver.
2016-12-02 15:48:44,842 [1] INFO  - Using implementation type 'Sdl.Web.Mvc.Statics.BaseStaticFileManager' for interface IStaticFileManager.
2016-12-02 15:48:44,842 [1] INFO  - No implementation type configured for optional interface IUnknownLocalizationHandler.
2016-12-02 15:48:44,967 [1] DEBUG - Model type 'Sdl.Web.Modules.Core.Models.ItemList' has semantic type(s) 's:ItemList'.
2016-12-02 15:48:44,967 [1] DEBUG -     Registered property 'Headline' as semantic property 's:headline'
2016-12-02 15:48:44,967 [1] DEBUG -     Registered property 'ItemListElements' as semantic property 's:itemListElement'
2016-12-02 15:48:44,967 [1] DEBUG - Model type 'Sdl.Web.Modules.Core.Models.Article' has semantic type(s) 's:Article'.
2016-12-02 15:48:44,967 [1] DEBUG -     Registered property 'Headline' as semantic property 's:headline'
2016-12-02 15:48:44,967 [1] DEBUG -     Registered property 'Image' as semantic property 's:image'
2016-12-02 15:48:44,967 [1] DEBUG -     Registered property 'Date' as semantic property 's:dateCreated'
2016-12-02 15:48:44,967 [1] DEBUG -     Registered property 'Description' as semantic property 's:about'
2016-12-02 15:48:44,967 [1] DEBUG -     Registered property 'ArticleBody' as semantic property 's:articleBody'
2016-12-02 15:48:44,983 [1] DEBUG - Model type 'Sdl.Web.Modules.Core.Models.Download' has semantic type(s) 's:DataDownload s:MediaObject'.
2016-12-02 15:48:44,983 [1] DEBUG -     Registered property 'Description' as semantic property 's:name s:description'
2016-12-02 15:48:44,983 [1] DEBUG -     Registered property 'Url' as semantic property 's:contentUrl'
2016-12-02 15:48:44,983 [1] DEBUG -     Registered property 'FileSize' as semantic property 's:contentSize'
2016-12-02 15:48:44,983 [1] DEBUG - Model type 'Sdl.Web.Modules.Core.Models.Image' has semantic type(s) 's:ImageObject s:MediaObject'.
2016-12-02 15:48:44,983 [1] DEBUG -     Registered property 'AlternateText' as semantic property 's:name'
2016-12-02 15:48:44,983 [1] DEBUG -     Registered property 'Url' as semantic property 's:contentUrl'
2016-12-02 15:48:44,983 [1] DEBUG -     Registered property 'FileSize' as semantic property 's:contentSize'
2016-12-02 15:48:44,983 [1] DEBUG - Model type 'Sdl.Web.Modules.Core.Models.Place' has semantic type(s) 's:Place'.
2016-12-02 15:48:44,983 [1] DEBUG -     Registered property 'Name' as semantic property 's:name'
2016-12-02 15:48:44,983 [1] DEBUG -     Registered property 'Image' as semantic property 's:image'
2016-12-02 15:48:44,983 [1] DEBUG -     Registered property 'Address' as semantic property 's:address'
2016-12-02 15:48:44,983 [1] DEBUG -     Registered property 'Telephone' as semantic property 's:telephone'
2016-12-02 15:48:44,983 [1] DEBUG -     Registered property 'FaxNumber' as semantic property 's:faxNumber'
2016-12-02 15:48:44,983 [1] DEBUG -     Registered property 'Email' as semantic property 's:email'
2016-12-02 15:48:44,983 [1] DEBUG -     Registered property 'Location' as semantic property 's:geo'
2016-12-02 15:48:44,983 [1] DEBUG - Model type 'Sdl.Web.Modules.Core.Models.YouTubeVideo' has semantic type(s) 's:VideoObject s:MediaObject'.
2016-12-02 15:48:44,983 [1] DEBUG -     Registered property 'Url' as semantic property 's:contentUrl'
2016-12-02 15:48:44,983 [1] DEBUG -     Registered property 'FileSize' as semantic property 's:contentSize'
2016-12-02 15:48:44,983 [1] DEBUG - Model type 'Sdl.Web.Modules.Core.Models.ContentList`1[[Sdl.Web.Modules.Core.Models.Teaser, Sdl.Web.Modules.Core, Version=1.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]' has semantic type(s) 's:ItemList'.
2016-12-02 15:48:44,983 [1] DEBUG -     Registered property 'Headline' as semantic property 's:headline'
2016-12-02 15:48:44,983 [1] DEBUG - Model type 'Sdl.Web.Modules.Core.Models.ContentList`1[[Sdl.Web.Modules.Core.Models.Article, Sdl.Web.Modules.Core, Version=1.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]' has semantic type(s) 's:ItemList'.
2016-12-02 15:48:44,983 [1] DEBUG -     Registered property 'Headline' as semantic property 's:headline'
2016-12-02 15:48:44,999 [1] DEBUG - Found Device Family 'featurephone'.
2016-12-02 15:48:44,999 [1] DEBUG - Found Device Family 'smartphone'.
2016-12-02 15:48:44,999 [1] DEBUG - Found Device Family 'tablet'.
2016-12-02 15:48:44,999 [1] DEBUG - Found Device Family 'desktop'.
2016-12-02 15:48:46,124 [5] WARN  - No matching Localization found for URL 'http://localhost:90/'. Sending HTTP 404 (Not Found) response.
2016-12-02 16:03:44,084 [21] DEBUG - Exception occurred in DynamicMappingsRetriever.GetPublicationMapping('http://localhost:90/'):
Sdl.Web.Delivery.Service.InvalidResourceException: Unable to locate resource: ---> Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceQueryException: An error occurred while processing this request. ---> Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceClientException: {"error":{"code":"3500","message":"Can't resolve publication from given URL: http://localhost:90/"}}
```

The last line seems to be the reason of this problem but I have no idea how to solve this.

### MORE INFORMATION

I checked the mapping.

```
{
      "Id":"Mapping3","ExtensionProperties":[

      ],"CmEnvironmentId":"SDLWebcm_WINDOWSATCI7E1","PublicationId":"tcm:0-13063-1","EnvironmentPurpose":"Staging","WebApplicationId":"Website2_RootWebApp","RelativeUrl":"/","PrimaryMappedUrl":"http://MyServerIP:90/","IsOffline":false
    }
```

Any advice would be appreciated.
Thanks.

### UPDATE

DXA site log

```
2016-12-02 17:19:39,155 [1] INFO  - -------- Initializing DXA Framework v1.6.0.223 --------
2016-12-02 17:19:39,202 [1] INFO  - Using implementation type 'Sdl.Web.Tridion.DefaultCacheProvider' for interface ICacheProvider.
2016-12-02 17:19:39,202 [1] INFO  - Using implementation type 'Sdl.Web.Tridion.Mapping.DefaultContentProvider' for interface IContentProvider.
2016-12-02 17:19:39,202 [1] INFO  - Using implementation type 'Sdl.Web.Tridion.Navigation.StaticNavigationProvider' for interface INavigationProvider.
2016-12-02 17:19:40,062 [1] INFO  - Using implementation type 'Sdl.Web.Tridion.Context.ContextServiceClaimsProvider' for interface IContextClaimsProvider.
2016-12-02 17:19:40,062 [1] INFO  - Using implementation type 'Sdl.Web.Tridion.Linking.DefaultLinkResolver' for interface ILinkResolver.
2016-12-02 17:19:40,062 [1] INFO  - Using implementation type 'Sdl.Web.Tridion.Mapping.DefaultRichTextProcessor' for interface IRichTextProcessor.
2016-12-02 17:19:40,062 [1] INFO  - No implementation type configured for optional interface IConditionalEntityEvaluator.
2016-12-02 17:19:40,062 [1] INFO  - Using implementation type 'Sdl.Web.Mvc.Html.BaseMediaHelper' for interface IMediaHelper.
2016-12-02 17:19:40,062 [1] INFO  - Using implementation type 'Sdl.Web.Tridion.CdApiLocalizationResolver' for interface ILocalizationResolver.
2016-12-02 17:19:40,062 [1] INFO  - Using implementation type 'Sdl.Web.Mvc.Statics.BaseStaticFileManager' for interface IStaticFileManager.
2016-12-02 17:19:40,062 [1] INFO  - No implementation type configured for optional interface IUnknownLocalizationHandler.
2016-12-02 17:19:40,108 [1] DEBUG - Model type 'Sdl.Web.Modules.Core.Models.ItemList' has semantic type(s) 's:ItemList'.
2016-12-02 17:19:40,108 [1] DEBUG -     Registered property 'Headline' as semantic property 's:headline'
2016-12-02 17:19:40,108 [1] DEBUG -     Registered property 'ItemListElements' as semantic property 's:itemListElement'
2016-12-02 17:19:40,108 [1] DEBUG - Model type 'Sdl.Web.Modules.Core.Models.Article' has semantic type(s) 's:Article'.
2016-12-02 17:19:40,108 [1] DEBUG -     Registered property 'Headline' as semantic property 's:headline'
2016-12-02 17:19:40,108 [1] DEBUG -     Registered property 'Image' as semantic property 's:image'
2016-12-02 17:19:40,108 [1] DEBUG -     Registered property 'Date' as semantic property 's:dateCreated'
2016-12-02 17:19:40,108 [1] DEBUG -     Registered property 'Description' as semantic property 's:about'
2016-12-02 17:19:40,108 [1] DEBUG -     Registered property 'ArticleBody' as semantic property 's:articleBody'
2016-12-02 17:19:40,108 [1] DEBUG - Model type 'Sdl.Web.Modules.Core.Models.Download' has semantic type(s) 's:DataDownload s:MediaObject'.
2016-12-02 17:19:40,108 [1] DEBUG -     Registered property 'Description' as semantic property 's:name s:description'
2016-12-02 17:19:40,108 [1] DEBUG -     Registered property 'Url' as semantic property 's:contentUrl'
2016-12-02 17:19:40,108 [1] DEBUG -     Registered property 'FileSize' as semantic property 's:contentSize'
2016-12-02 17:19:40,108 [1] DEBUG - Model type 'Sdl.Web.Modules.Core.Models.Image' has semantic type(s) 's:ImageObject s:MediaObject'.
2016-12-02 17:19:40,108 [1] DEBUG -     Registered property 'AlternateText' as semantic property 's:name'
2016-12-02 17:19:40,108 [1] DEBUG -     Registered property 'Url' as semantic property 's:contentUrl'
2016-12-02 17:19:40,108 [1] DEBUG -     Registered property 'FileSize' as semantic property 's:contentSize'
2016-12-02 17:19:40,108 [1] DEBUG - Model type 'Sdl.Web.Modules.Core.Models.Place' has semantic type(s) 's:Place'.
2016-12-02 17:19:40,108 [1] DEBUG -     Registered property 'Name' as semantic property 's:name'
2016-12-02 17:19:40,124 [1] DEBUG -     Registered property 'Image' as semantic property 's:image'
2016-12-02 17:19:40,124 [1] DEBUG -     Registered property 'Address' as semantic property 's:address'
2016-12-02 17:19:40,124 [1] DEBUG -     Registered property 'Telephone' as semantic property 's:telephone'
2016-12-02 17:19:40,124 [1] DEBUG -     Registered property 'FaxNumber' as semantic property 's:faxNumber'
2016-12-02 17:19:40,124 [1] DEBUG -     Registered property 'Email' as semantic property 's:email'
2016-12-02 17:19:40,124 [1] DEBUG -     Registered property 'Location' as semantic property 's:geo'
2016-12-02 17:19:40,124 [1] DEBUG - Model type 'Sdl.Web.Modules.Core.Models.YouTubeVideo' has semantic type(s) 's:VideoObject s:MediaObject'.
2016-12-02 17:19:40,124 [1] DEBUG -     Registered property 'Url' as semantic property 's:contentUrl'
2016-12-02 17:19:40,124 [1] DEBUG -     Registered property 'FileSize' as semantic property 's:contentSize'
2016-12-02 17:19:40,124 [1] DEBUG - Model type 'Sdl.Web.Modules.Core.Models.ContentList`1[[Sdl.Web.Modules.Core.Models.Teaser, Sdl.Web.Modules.Core, Version=1.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]' has semantic type(s) 's:ItemList'.
2016-12-02 17:19:40,124 [1] DEBUG -     Registered property 'Headline' as semantic property 's:headline'
2016-12-02 17:19:40,124 [1] DEBUG - Model type 'Sdl.Web.Modules.Core.Models.ContentList`1[[Sdl.Web.Modules.Core.Models.Article, Sdl.Web.Modules.Core, Version=1.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]' has semantic type(s) 's:ItemList'.
2016-12-02 17:19:40,124 [1] DEBUG -     Registered property 'Headline' as semantic property 's:headline'
2016-12-02 17:19:40,124 [1] DEBUG - Found Device Family 'featurephone'.
2016-12-02 17:19:40,124 [1] DEBUG - Found Device Family 'smartphone'.
2016-12-02 17:19:40,124 [1] DEBUG - Found Device Family 'tablet'.
2016-12-02 17:19:40,124 [1] DEBUG - Found Device Family 'desktop'.
2016-12-02 17:19:40,265 [10] WARN  - No matching Localization found for URL 'http://SERVERIP:90/'. Sending HTTP 404 (Not Found) response.
2016-12-02 17:20:43,686 [9] WARN  - No matching Localization found for URL 'http://SERVERIP:90/'. Sending HTTP 404 (Not Found) response.
2016-12-02 17:20:46,483 [11] WARN  - No matching Localization found for URL 'http://SERVERIP:90/'. Sending HTTP 404 (Not Found) response.
2016-12-02 17:20:47,530 [5] WARN  - No matching Localization found for URL 'http://SERVERIP:90/'. Sending HTTP 404 (Not Found) response.
2016-12-02 17:23:52,810 [8] WARN  - No matching Localization found for URL 'http://SERVERIP:90/'. Sending HTTP 404 (Not Found) response.
2016-12-02 17:23:52,857 [11] WARN  - No matching Localization found for URL 'http://SERVERIP:90/favicon.ico'. Sending HTTP 404 (Not Found) response.
```

Site information
[image]

Comment: The information you provide is a bit confusing: the error message you show has `http://MyServer:90`, but the log file shows `http://localhost:90` and the extract from Topology Manager shows `http://MyServerIP:90`. This may be introduced by your attempt to anonymize, but it might also be the cause of the problem.

Comment: Yes, I have changed the URL from localhost to MyServerIP according to Raj's answer, but it didn't work. And the log file's information is ServerIP nowm not the localhost.

Comment: Can you update your Question with what you have in Topology Manager now and the error you get in your DXA log now (exactly, not edited)?

Comment: OK. I have updated.

Comment: Did you configure the Discovery Service of `CdEnvironment2` in you DXA Web App's `web.config` ?

Comment: You mean the discovery-service-uri? I checked that it has the correct value(Discovery of CdEnvironment2).

Comment: Weird. You could try to force synchronize the Disovery Service with Topology Manager using `Sync-TtmCdEnvironment CdEnvironment2`.

Comment: I tried that as I saw your comment under http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/15002/error-while-accessing-dxa-1-4-website. But after that my publishing went failed at the last step, then I restarted my server, publish succeeded but still unable to access the site,

Comment: I recommend contacting SDL Support for further analysis, then.

Answer (score 1):

This is occurring because your URL(s) are not registered in Topology manager.

PS C:\Windows\system32> Set-TtmWebsite -id Website1 -BaseUrls "http://localhost:port", "http://myserver:90"

if you want to access same website with two different Urls

Comment: The URL is registered when running the ttm-prepare.ps1, isn't that? I checked the website and it has a baseURL which is "http://localhost:90". should I change the localhost to my Server IP?

Comment: are you using any logic(e.g ) which triggers before localization object is initialized e.g Owin?

Comment: No, I didn't use those. Simply configured according to SDL documentation.